# Can you add a property to a JavaScript function inside the function body?

Tags: javascript

I know that you can do this:

```
var someFunc = function(){
    //do something
}
someFunc.newProperty = "blah";
```

However, this doesn't seem to do the same thing.

```
var someFunc = function(){
    var newProperty = "blah";
    //do something
}
```

In the second case, if I try to call someFunc.newProperty, that doesn't seem to return "blah".  What is the difference?

Comment: That looks like a XY problem... what exactly are you trying to achieve by that? I can give you an explanation of the difference, but I don't think that this going to help you solve your overall problem.

Comment: `var newProperty` declares a local variable, not a property.

Comment: My question stems from the way Angular expects functions to be annotated with injection dependencies.  When defining an annotated function in Angular, you can set the $inject property of the function with the array of dependencies.  The other way is to specify it inline as a array containing the dependencies and the anonymous inline function.  I was trying to understand why I cannot specify the $inject property inside the anonymous function body, rather than declaring it inline.  I think I understand now from Felix's answer.  I'm also using Typescript, so that made it harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference?

In the first case you are assigning a [**property** to the function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties). In the second case you are defining a [**local variable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) inside the function, which only exists when the function is executed. Local variables do not magically become properties of the function object.

---

If you give the function a name, you can easily assign a property to it:

```
var someFunc = function name() {
    name.newProperty = "blah";
    //do something
}
```

But the property still won't exists until the function is executed. So,

```
someFunc.newProperty;
```

doesn't work, but

```
someFunc();
someFunc.newProperty;
```

does.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, newProperty is an attribute of the someFunc object. In the second case newProperty is a local variable, which means it gets placed on the stack during function execution and disappears afterwards.